# How to set username / passwd in paho.mqtt.subscribe

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

Here my script from [subscribe_simple.py](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/subscribe_simple.py)

```
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe

topics = ['#']

m = subscribe.simple(topics, hostname="eu.thethings.network", retained=False, msg_count=2)

for a in m:
    print(str(a.topic))
    print(str(a.payload))
```

Return me this as error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MQTT_subscribe_simple.py", line 15, in <module>
    m = subscribe.simple(topics, hostname="eu.thethings.network", retained=False, msg_count=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py", line 252, in simple
    clean_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py", line 165, in callback
    client.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1481, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1003, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1284, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1849, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2311, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2372, in _handle_connack
    self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py", line 29, in _on_connect
    raise mqtt.MQTTException(paho.connack_string(rc))
paho.mqtt.MQTTException: Connection Refused: not authorised.
```

I put this line before the loop with the right values

```
m.username_pw_set(username, password)
```

No issue

Is it possible to use authentication with paho.mqtt.subscribe and how to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py#L168) it looks like you can pass in an auth object to the `subscribe.simple()` call.

e.g.

```
m = subscribe.simple(topics, hostname="eu.thethings.network", retained=False, msg_count=2, auth={'username':"foo", 'password':"bar"})
```